# assigning shortcut key to launch python

Tags: python, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, compiz

I'm an ubuntu user. As you know, python promt is a very useful tool. And I want to replace my calculator app with it. What I want is a new terminal with python shell running on it to show up when I press a key combination. I can assign scripts to shortcut keys with compiz-config settings manager, but I can't get the result I want. 'gnome-terminal;python3;' launches a new terminal without python running on it. Looks like it starts python in background on tty7. So how can I get the result I want.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This would really be better on something like askubuntu.com. This site is more about direct programming questions, eg "My code doesn't work, how do I fix it".

Comment: Hi Saga, If any of the answers worked for you, please consider accepting it. (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you. Better not add a comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it:

```
gnome-terminal --command python3
```

As you have certainly guessed, `--command` is the parameter to use to execute a command inside `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: great it works for me! but what about ipython? when i try with 'gnome-terminal --command ipython' it is pop-up and closing immediately.